# Column headers of Shiny data table gets shifted

Tags: shiny, dt

When I run my Shiny app, the headers of my data tables get shifted to the left. See below.[image]Say this table is on Tab A.

The headers get aligned correctly when I click on a different tab (Tab B),then click on Tab A again. See below for the corrected headers.

[image]

Any idea what's causing it? Below is a simplified version of my code. Thanks in advance!

**ui.R**

```
    library("shinythemes")

    fluidPage(title = "Segmentation App", theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),

        navbarPage("Segmentation", id = "allResults",
            tabPanel(value='result_scorecard', title='ScoreCard', 
                     sidebarLayout(
                       sidebarPanel(
                         h4("Select a cluster solution to profile"),
                         width = 3
                       ),

                       mainPanel(
                         verticalLayout(
                           helpText(strong('Summary of Cluster Solutions')),
                           column(DT::dataTableOutput('out_best'), width = 12),                              
                           helpText(strong('ScoreCard Table')),
                           column(DT::dataTableOutput('out_scorecard'), width = 12)

                         )
                       )
                     )
            ),

            tabPanel(value='profile', title='Profile', 
                     verticalLayout(
                         column(DT::dataTableOutput('prop_by_cluster_ind'), width=10)
                      )
            )
        )
    )
```

**server.R**

```
function(input, output, session) {

    best_sols <- reactive({
     A <- c(100, 101, 201)
     B <- c(100, 101, 201)
     C <- c(100, 101, 201)
     temp <- as.matrix(cbind(A, B, C))
     colnames(temp) <- c("A", "B", "C")
     rownames(temp) <- c("k=1","k=2","k=3")
     return(temp)
    })

    score_seg <- reactive({
      A <- c("solution=1","solution=2","solution=3","solution=4","solution=5")
      B <- c(100, 101, 201, 333, 444)
      C <- c(100, 101, 201, 333, 444)
      temp <- data.frame(A, B, C)
      colnames(temp) <- c("A", "B", "score_seg")
      return(temp)

    })

    profile_result_ind <- reactive({
      A1 <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")
      A2 <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")
      B <- c(100, 101, 201, 333, 444)
      C <- c(100, 101, 201, 333, 444)
      temp <- data.frame(A1, A2, B, C)
      colnames(temp) <- c("","","1","2")
      return(temp)
    })


    # Table 1

    output$out_best <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(best_sols(), caption = "", rownames = TRUE, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = 1)), paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE), selection='none') %>% formatRound(1:5, 3)
      #}
    })

    # Table 2

    output$out_scorecard <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(score_seg(), caption = "", rownames = F, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = 1)), paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE), selection='single') %>% formatRound(1:5, 3)
    })


    # Table 3
    output$prop_by_cluster_ind <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(profile_result_ind(), class= 'compact stripe', caption = '', rownames = F, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '300px', targets = 1), list(className = 'dt-left', targets="_all")), paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE)) %>% formatStyle(as.character(seq(1:2)))   
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

The headers will be aligned correctly if we change the autoWidth option to FALSE.

Comment: I have the same problem, `autowitdth=FALSE` resolve the problem but the dataframe use all the width available, 
Is there any other solution please ?

Comment: `autoWidth` is necessary if one wants to specify column width manually, see https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/29. There has to be another solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had a table with long rownames such as you and had a similar problem with offset column names, but setting **autoWidth=FALSE** did not solve the problem. I discovered that it was being caused by **scrollX=TRUE**. I changed **ScrollX=FALSE** and wrapped the datatable in a div with **overflow-x=TRUE** to regain the scroll feature:

```
div(style="overflow-x:auto",renderDataTable({tableName},options=list(scrollX=FALSE))
```