# How to solve shiny mis-alignment issue in datatable?

Tags: jquery, css, r, datatable, shiny

I am trying to

- make all columns in the datatable the same width
- align the datatable (both header and its content) to the left
- enable horizontal scrolling once it reaches mainPanel width

but my datatable gets automatically centered to the mainPanel, its header and content are also misaligned.

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Test Example"), 

   mainPanel(
     width = 10, 
     dataTableOutput("cars.table")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$cars.table <- renderDataTable({
      t(cars[1:10, ]) %>% 
       datatable(class = "compact small", 
                 options = list(columnDefs = list(list(width = "25px", targets = "_all")), scrollX = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE, 
                                paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Update 2019/05/03:

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287971/column-headers-of-shiny-data-table-gets-shifted) states that such issue was caused by `autoWidth = TRUE`, but there is no solution under the question, and if we want to adjust column width, we can't delete `autoWidth = TRUE` as well.

Answer (score 0):

For alignment you can use `className = dt-left`.

And I guess the argument `fillContainer = T' does the job for scrolling.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test Example"), 

  mainPanel(
    width = 10, 
    dataTableOutput("cars.table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$cars.table <- renderDataTable({
    t(cars[1:10, ]) %>% 
      datatable(class = "compact small", fillContainer = T, 
                options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', width = "25px", targets = "_all")), scrollX = TRUE, 
                               paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: although you set the width to be 25px, but the whole width automatically changed to the width of datatable

Comment: you can test it by changing the width to 50 px