# Plotly and DT tables with Flexdashboard

Tags: r, dt, r-plotly, flexdashboard

I'm having difficulties with the placement of plots and tables within `flexdashboard`. Here's a reprex:

````
---
title: "FlexDashboard"
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: column
---
              
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library("flexdashboard")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly")
library("DT")
```


```{r}
library(datasets)
data(iris)
iris <- iris

```


Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### **Chart**
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labor et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=8}
ggplotly(ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point())

```



### Chart B

```{r}



```




Column {data-width=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
iris %>% 
  datatable(
          rownames = FALSE,
          class = 'cell-border stripe',
          extensions = c('Buttons', 'KeyTable'), 
          options = list(dom = 't',
                         autoWidth = TRUE,
                         buttons = c('copy', 'excel',  'print'),
                         keys = TRUE)
          )

```
````

**There are two problems:**

1. The plotly graph is cut off. I tried to play with `fig.width` and `fig.height` to no avail.
2. The DT table does not display the buttons and the header row is not aligned

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the plotly graph being cutoff is that you mixed text with a chart in one "container". You can have only "one" content per container.

If you want to have text on your dashboad you can put it at the top of the page (Option 1)  at the top of a column (Option 2) or you can add it as a text annotation below your chart (Option 3). My code below shows examples of these three options. And of course option 4 would be to have separate containers for the text and the chart.

Concerning your second datatable issue. The alignment issue arises because of `autoWidth=TRUE`. With this information I did a search in the internet. Unfortunately I was not able to come up with a solution to this, except for setting `autoWidth=FALSE`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287971/column-headers-of-shiny-data-table-gets-shifted).

BTW: I would suggest to split the question in two, i.e. ask two different questions. While both issues are related to flexdahsboard, the issues are quite different. Focusing one each issue separately will make it easier to answer, make it easier for others to find the question and a possible answer, allows for making minimal exmaples, ...

````
    ---
    title: "FlexDashboard"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: column
    ---
                  
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(DT)
    ```
    
    **Option 1** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labor et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    
    Column {data-width=500}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    **Option 2** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labor et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    
    ### **Chart**
    
    ```{r}
    ggplotly(ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + geom_point())
    ```
    
    > **Option 3** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labor et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    
    ### Chart B
    
    ```{r}
    
    
    
    ```
    
    Column
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ### Chart B
    
    ```{r}
    iris %>% 
      datatable(
              rownames = FALSE,
              class = 'cell-border stripe',
              extensions = c('Buttons', 'KeyTable'), 
              options = list(dom = 't',
                             autoWidth = TRUE,
                             columnDefs = list(
                               list(className = 'dt-center',
                                    targets = 0:4)),
                             buttons = c('copy', 'excel',  'print'),
                             keys = TRUE
                             )
              )
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 
**Option 1** spans the entire dashboard
**Option 2**, as you indicate, places the content before the chart. This would be unusual for a figure caption
**Option 3** results in a cutoff graph.
I also tried `fig.cap = "lorem ipsum..."` in the chunk option which has the same effect of cutting off the graph.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to split into two questions. On the DT problem, setting `autowidth=FALSE` worked. However, I'm still unable to display the buttons (`copy`, `excel`, `print`)

Comment: Hm. Option 1 was just to show the general options of adding text. Option 3 renders fine on my machine. See the image I added.